# Window.onload and run after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I open a iframe after the page is fully loaded with this javascript code:

```
<script>
    function loadFrame() {        
    var iframe = document.getElementById("defframe");
    iframe.src = "/frame.php"
};
window.onload = loadFrame;
</script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<iframe id="defframe" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" src="about:blank" />   </iframe>
```

This works perfect but I have to load this iframe 10 seconds after the page is loaded.

**1.** wait for window.onload

**2.** If window.onload is ready, wait 10 seconds more before fire.

**I tried**:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function loadFrame() {        
    var iframe = document.getElementById("defframe");
    iframe.src = "/frame.php"

    setTimeout(defframe, 10000)
};   
</script>
```

Without success. Thank you very much

Comment: Why wait 10 seconds?

Comment: Because when the Iframe is loading, its not possible to click any link on the website until the content in the iframe is fully loaded. When the frame load first after 10 seconds. The User is reading and the probability that the user want click a link during the frame is loading is a bit more less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is leave your **function** as it is, just call it in different way. Please follow below code::
**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="defframe" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" src="about:blank" >   </iframe>
```

**JS:**

```
function loadFrame() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("defframe");
    iframe.src = "/frame.php"
};
window.onload = setTimeout(loadFrame, 10000);
```

Working JSfiddle code:: https://jsfiddle.net/rnrztx1d/1/

Comment: @labu77 Happy to help you. :)

Comment: `onload` should be assigned a function. This may result in issues in some Browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
window.onload = function loadFrame() {        
    setTimeout(function(){
          var iframe = document.getElementById("defframe");
          iframe.src = "/frame.php"

    }, 10000)
};
```

in window.load you can set up setTimeout function for 10 seconds.

Alternative way,

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(loadFrame(), 10000);
};

function loadFrame() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("defframe");
  iframe.src = "/frame.php"
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` takes an unexecuted function.

Answer (score 0):

We have to put code inside the **set Time out** method.

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="defframe" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" src="about:blank" />   </iframe>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function loadDefFrame() {
 setTimeout(function () {
 loadFrame(); //call your method
},10000)};
```

**Complete Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<script>

  window.onload = function loadDefFrame() {
   setTimeout(function () {
   loadFrame(); //call your method
  },10000)};

  function loadFrame() {        
   var iframe = document.getElementById("defframe");
   iframe.src = "/frame.php"
  };

</script>
<body>

<iframe id="defframe" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" src="about:blank" /></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you too for your kind help. your code is working also.

Comment: Happy to help. happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `onload` process in `setTimeout`

```
window.onload = function loadFrame() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("defframe");
        iframe.src = "/frame.php";
    }, 10000);
};
```